# Can we please make sense with close reasons?

Tags: discussion

[What is the difference between Canvera and Karizma wedding albums? [on hold]](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/59934/what-is-the-difference-between-canvera-and-karizma-wedding-albums) was closed because:

> "Questions seeking product or service recommendations are off-topic because they tend to become obsolete quickly. Instead, describe your situation and the specific problem you're trying to solve."

Really? He didn't ask which to pick, he asked about the differences. There's no product or service recommendation request there at all, this close reason makes no sense to me, can someone explain it?

Really, maybe I'm grumpy today, but the reason meta has been suddenly flooded with posts like this is because closures haven't been making any sense.

Comment: If anything I could see it incorrectly being marked as too localized, but that isn't the case either (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4818/what-questions-should-be-closed-with-reason-too-localized). I didn't vote on it either way though.

Comment: You were quite right to reopen IMHO.

Comment: @abbyhairboat - Thanks. :)

Answer (score -1):

If the question had been "is there a difference in paper quality between the C and K albums", or "What should I look for in a quality wedding album" I would have thought that a good question.

Or if he had stated that he wanted large, thick pages or quality binding.  But as it stands,
"What is the difference between Canvera and Karizma wedding albums?" just begs for subjective answers.  I do think it's something of a shopping question, it's broad and it's probably going to lead to opinion-based answers.  Might not quite fit any of those fully, but I think it strays well into all three areas.

I see your point, and that made by Bart, that there might conceivably be good objective answers so I don't have a problem with it being reopened, but I don't think it was an egregiously bad decision to close it either.

Comment: I would have left it, most likely, if the reason made any sense, but it didn't and we've handled pros/cons questions readily before. So all that tells me that those that voted didn't really have a reason and that's not really what we should be doing.